# Unable to launch the configured Visual Studio development web server

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, vb.net, iis

I'm using VS2017 and when I tried to run my app just standard noting extra with IIS express it fails.

Error:

> An error occurred launching IIS Express. Unable to launch the configured visual studio development web server. Uncaught exception thrown by method called reflection.

I've set the port to 8080 instead of 56000.

Any ideas how what is wrong? Yes I installed IIS Express but it's not running in the background. I've tried to start VS in Administrtor mode but no luck. I've also deleted the .vs folder and restarted but again no luck.

Comment: Sounds like you left some wrong assemblies in the `bin` folder. Maybe you should remove that folder instead and try again.

Answer (score -1):

According to [this blog](https://askguanyu.wordpress.com/2017/06/07/visual-studio-2015-2017-cannot-launch-asp-net-iis-express-issue-and-workaround/), the following steps should fix the issue:

1. close all Visual Studio instances
2. go to your ASP.NET project/solution folder, delete “.vs” hidden folder
3. click “Start”, search IISExpress, go to IISExpress folder, go upper level and delete whole IISExpress folder
4. start Visual Studio with Administrator privilege
5. create a fresh new ASP.NET project
6. run this project, this time you should see IIS Express is launched by Visual Studio correctly
7. close this solution but not close Visual Studio, open the ASP.NET project which you have problem with, and run it now, you should see IIS Express is launched correctly

Comment: Performing just the first two steps fixed the issue for me.